# Rails: How do I

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have started a new Rails project with postgres as its database. I also have a `.pgsql` file.

Looking at the file, I can see it contains instructions of how to build that database as well as its data. (It looks like a bunch of migrations and seed data all in one.)

I want to build my project's database from this file. My Google-foo is failing me on this one and I'm not sure where to start.

Is there a command I can run to import the structure and data into my project? Is it possible? What do I need to do to get up and running?

Comment: This file is your db dump. You need to use pg_restore to restore your dump in database. Do it by `pg_restore` command. It's not rails case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and go to your project directory. Run below line of codes.

```
$rake db:drop db:create ## To drop and create fresh DB.

$pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U <user> -d <your db> <pgsql backup file path>  ## Import data from DB backup file
```

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Thanks. I ran `psql -d thing_development -f dumped_db.pgsql` but found I needed to create a couple of users first. `createuser --superuser postgres` and `createuser --superuser rails` did it. After importing the db, I created the schema with `rails db:schema:dump`